# how to handle the input buffer in c

Tags: c, getchar, input-buffer

I'm new to c programming and I'm facing this problem with my program
I have a loop that gets a char form the input buffer

```
while(c = getchar()){
    if(c == '\n') break;
    if(c == '1') Add();
    if(c == '2') getInput(); // this is where the headache starts
    ....
}
```

here is the getInput() function

```
void getInput()
{ 
    char ch = getchar();
    if(ch == '1') doSomething();
    ....
}
```

but when calling getchar() from the getInput() function it only gets characters that were left in the input buffer from the last call of getchar(). and what i want it to do is to get newly typed characters.

I've been googling for two hours for a decent way to clear the input buffer but nothing helped. So a link to a tutorial or an article or something is very appreciated and if there's another way to implement this then please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there will be `==` comparison operator rather than `=` assignment operator in the `if` condition in this code.

```
while(c = getchar()){
    if(c = '\n') break;
    if(c = '1') Add();
    if(c = '2') getInput(); // this is where the headache starts
    ....
}
```

And for stop taking input try `EOF` which from keyboard can be given by prssing `CTRL+D`.

EDIT : The problem is with the `\n` which is actually taken as input when you press `ENTER` key on the key board. So change just one line of code.

`if (c ==`\n`) break;` to `if (c == EOF ) break;` and as I said `EOF` is the end of input.

Then your code will work fine.

Flow of code :

```
step 1: suppose `2` is input 
step 2: getInput() is called
step 3: suppose `1` as input  // in getInput
step 4: doSomething() is called  // from getInput
step 5: After completion of doSomething again come back to while loop , 

but in your case you have already given `\n` character as an input 

when you pressed `1` and `ENTER`.And thus loop terminates.
```

but after changing the code as I said , this should work.

NOTE: To understand code flow and for debugging purposes it's best practice to put `printf()` in various places in functions and see the output as which lines are executing and which are not.

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't works because between step 1 and step 3 input buffer has to be flushed. but here it is not flushed and the input buffer from the first call of getchar() will affect the comparison in getInput()

Comment: are you taking input in `Add()` function also , if yes then there may be a problem due to that (You haven't shown us the code of Add) ? Otherwise code worked fine on my system.

Comment: I'm not taking input in add()(in fact am just calling printf) and i have changed the code to what you said if you want i can post the code but it's not very well commented and too long

Answer (score 1):

This should work: (Example of clearing input buffer)

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
  int   ch;
  char  buf[BUFSIZ];

  puts("Flushing input");

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

  printf ("Enter some text: ");

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
  {
    printf ("You entered: %s", buf);
  }

  return 0;
}

/*
 * Program output:
 *
 Flushing input
 blah blah blah blah
 Enter some text: hello there
 You entered: hello there
 *
 */
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but as you see in the code am trying to get one character that will describe a choice and not a whole string. so what i want is just get the character compare it to another and forget about what's left in the input stream and then call another getchar().